# Грид с возможностью перерисовывать строки отдельно и извне

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно реализовать такой DataGrid, где возможно помимо просто вывода данных иметь возможность перерисовать отдельную строку, изменив ее данные, причем не только внутри React-компонента, но и извне его, то есть каким-то образом должен быть доступ к строкам по идентификатору.

Может у кого-то был такой опыт, и он мне подкинет идею как такое реализовать?

P.S. Готовые использовать не хочу, т.к. ситуация такая что проще самим написать чем прикручивать готовое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь `redux`. Храните список (данные) в `store`.

Напишите `action` который будет изменять данные одной строки. И везде где вам нужно менять данные - пользуйтесь этим `action`.